# MS Excel - VLOOKUP Formula doesnt work for one value

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

[image]

When I run VLOOKUP Formula for 'E' it doesn't find the appropriate value. But all the other formulas gives the correct value as shown in the picture. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Check if there is a space behind the 'E' in the look-up table or in column J

Comment: thank u for the suggestion. but no. I already checked for extra spaces.

Comment: Please check if the cells really contain the same value. Enter "=J4=M3" in any empty cell and see if that returns TRUE

Comment: Yes. It returns TRUE.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue unless one of the Es has a space or unprintable character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify a 4th argument in your `VLOOKUP` function, in which case it defaults to TRUE and expects a lookup range sorted ascending (which you don't have)

Fix by adding a 4th argument of `FALSE` or `0`, e.g. This formula in K2 copied down

`=VLOOKUP(J2,M$2:N$7,2,FALSE)`

Another option would be to sort your table based on the first column.....but that will also mean you will get an "approximate match" which might not be appropriate in this case, e.g. if you make J2 = `"X"` then with an approximate match the `VLOOKUP` will return `"WEST"`

See excel help on `VLOOKUP` for parameter explanations

Answer (score -1):

Try copying M3 and pasting values (Alt E-S-V) in J4 and J10.